# How to store the result of a function in a list?

Tags: python, list

I have this function:

```
def second(n):
    z =0
    while z  < n:
        z = z +1
        for i in range(n):
            print(z)
```

which produces this output for `second(3)`:

```
1
1
1
2
2
2
3
3
3
```

How can I store these in a list for further use?

Comment: Please note that the list you are creating here can also be directly defined as `[1+x/n for x in xrange(n*n)]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print doesn't save the results - it just sends them (one at a time) to standard output (stdout) for display on the screen. To get an in order copy of the results I humbly suggest you turn this into a [generator function](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) by using the `yield` keyword. For example:

```
>>> def second(n):
...     z =0
...     while z  < n:
...         z = z +1
...         for i in range(n):
...             yield z
... 
>>> print list(second(3))
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
```

In the above code `list()` expands the generator into a list of results that you can assign to a variable to save. If you want to save a list of all the results for `second(3)` you could alternatively do `results = list(second(3))` instead of printing it.

Answer (score 0):

You could utilise `itertools` here to return an iterable for you, and either loop over that, or explicitly convert to a `list`, eg:

```
from itertools import chain, repeat

def mysecond(n):
    return chain.from_iterable(repeat(i, n) for i in xrange(1, n))

print list(mysecond(3))
```

Comment: Needs to be `xrange(1, n+1)`

Comment: Seems to be 2x faster than other methods.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generator expression example:

```
list(j+1 for i in xrange(n) for j in [i]*n)
```

Comment: There's a mathematical way to express this better (without two loops); see my comment on the question.

Comment: Yes, I had noticed it and found it interesting.